# Pegar posição do mouse dentro de scroll pane

Tags: java, javafx

Como eu consigo pegar a posição do mouse dentro de um scroll pane em javafx? Eu tenho um app que faz uma operação de drag and drop dentro dele, e eu preciso dessa informação para posicionar o nó na tela.

O scroll pane é Pannable.

Se precisarem ver mais algum pedaço de có é só pedir, mas acho que postei o necessário para o entendimento ficar claro já.

[image: Onde foi dropado e a posição do vbar]   [image: Onde foi dropado e a posição do vbar]

```
public EventHandler<? super MouseEvent> getStartClassDrag(Node n, TipoClasse t) {
    return (e) ->{
        //this.ac_comp.setDisable(true);
        ClipboardContent cc = new ClipboardContent();
        cc.putUrl(FXMLFile.CLASSE);
        n.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY).setContent(cc);

        //Trecho de código original
        //sp_desktop.onDragDroppedProperty().set((evet) -> {

        //Solução
        pn_desktop.onDragDroppedProperty().set((evet) -> {
            if(evet.getDragboard().getUrl().equals(FXMLFile.CLASSE)) {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(FXMLFile.CLASSE));
                try {
                    loader.load();
                } catch (Exception err) { err.printStackTrace(); }
                ClasseController controller = loader.getController();
                controller.inicializar(this);
                controller.classe.setTipo(t);
                classes.add(controller);

                Point2D teste = new Point2D(evet.getX() + sp_desktop.getHvalue(), evet.getY() + sp_desktop.getVvalue());
                System.out.println(sp_desktop.getHvalue() + "x" + sp_desktop.getVvalue());

                teste = sp_desktop.parentToLocal(teste);

                relocateToPoint(teste.getX(), teste.getY(), controller.ap_classe);
                controller.ap_classe.setVisible(true);

            }
        });

        //Trecho de código original
        //sp_desktop.onDragOverProperty().set((evento) -> {

        //Solução
        pn_desktop.onDragOverProperty().set((evento) -> {
            if(evento.getDragboard().getUrl().equals(FXMLFile.CLASSE)) {
                evento.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
            }
            evento.consume();
        });

        n.onDragDoneProperty().set((aux) ->{
            sp_desktop.onDragDroppedProperty().set(null);
            sp_desktop.onDragOverProperty().set(null);
            ac_comp.setDisable(false);

        });
    };
}

protected void relocateToPoint(double x, double y, AnchorPane no) {
    no.setVisible(true);
    pn_desktop.getChildren().remove(no);
    pn_desktop.getChildren().add(no);
    no.setLayoutX(x - (no.getWidth() / 2));
    no.setLayoutY(y - (no.getHeight() / 2));
}
```

Comment: Nosso idioma é o **Português**, traduza sua pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenho um exemplo que fiz recentemente para movimentar minha janela.
Verifica se o código abaixo ajuda na solução.

```
    double xOffset = 0;
    double yOffset = 0;

    scrollPane.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> {
        // Nesse trecho de código será capturado a posição do mouse
        xOffset = event.getSceneX();
        yOffset = event.getSceneY();
    });
    scrollPane.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent event) -> {
        primaryStage.setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset);
        primaryStage.setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset);
    });
```

Comment: Valeu por responder. Acabei por descobrir que o problema era o nó em que o listener estava. Como pode ver, no exemplo que postei ele está no scroll pane, quando deveria estar no pane localizado dentro do scroll pane. Mesmo assim obrigado por ter tirado um tempo do seu dia para tentar me ajudar.